# Why the variable of sequence_length is useless in the ctc_beam_search_decoder of tensorflow-r1.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, beam-search

I'd like to generate a batch of sequence with a fixed shape [`batch_size`, `seq_lenth`]. 
Thus my code:

```
output, _ = tf.nn.ctc_beam_search_decoder(
        logits,
        tf.ones([batch_size])*seq_length,
        merge_repeated=False
        )
output = tf.sparse_to_dense(output[0], default_value=end_id)
```

where `logits` is output of `dynamic_rnn` with shape [`max_time`, `batch_size`, `cell_output_size`]. And I set `seq_length` to `40`. But the resulting `output` is not of shape [`batch_size`, `seq_length`]. And given that its shape is dynamic, I can not pad it to a fixed length. So what should I do to get the output with fixed size? Thanks in advance!